# Ajuda com montagem codigo deArrayList em Java (procura, inserir String)

Tags: java, array

Boa noite, tenho q desenvolver um codigo, mas estou com algumas duvidas, segue o codigo abaixo:

```
public class Aluno {
String nome;
int mat;
Aluno(String nome, int mat) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.mat = mat;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return nome + " - " + mat;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int escolha;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite o tamanho do array: ");
    int tamanho = input.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<>(tamanho);

    Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println(" Menu de opcões\n"
                + "1: Adicionar um nome na lista\n"
                + "2: adicionar um aluno em determinada posição do vetor\n"
                + "3: imprimir na tela o aluno em determinada posição do vetor\n"
                + "4: apagar (remover um aluno) de determinada posição do vetor\n"
                + "5: verificar de determinado aluno e/ou matrícula existem no vetor. Em caso positivo informar a posição do mesmo no vetor\n"
                + "6: imprimir a quantidade de alunos no vetor (não é o tamanho do vetor)\n"
                + "7: imprimir na tela todos os alunos\n"
                + "8:Sair");
        int opcoes = choice.nextInt();
        escolha = opcoes;
        switch (escolha) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Digite o nome do Aluno ");
                String nome = choice.next();
                System.out.println("digite o numero de matricula");
                int mat = choice.nextInt();
                Aluno novoAluno = new Aluno(nome, mat);
                alunos.add(novoAluno);
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("digite o nome do Aluno!!");
                nome = choice.next();
                System.out.println("digite a  matricula");
                mat = choice.nextInt();
                System.out.println("digite a posiçao que o aluno vai estar!!");
                int c = choice.nextInt();
                novoAluno = new Aluno(nome, mat);
                alunos.add(c, novoAluno);
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Informe o numero da posiçao?");
                int n = choice.nextInt();
                if (n < tamanho) {
                    System.out.println("na posicao " + n + " esta: " + alunos.set(n, null));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Fora dos limites");
                }
                break;
            case 4:

                System.out.println(alunos);

                System.out.println("qual posicao quer remover? ");
                int r = choice.nextInt();
                alunos.remove(r);
                break;

            case 5:
                System.out.println("qual aluno quer pesquisar");
                Scanner teste = new Scanner(System.in);
                String p = teste.nextLine();
                for (Aluno slt : alunos ){
                if (alunos.contains(p)) {
                    System.out.println("o aluno " + p + " esta na posiçao " + alunos.indexOf(p));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Esse aluno nao existe!!");
                }
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Existem " + alunos.size() + " Alunos no vetor");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("Os alunos sao: ");

                for (int i = 0; i < alunos.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(alunos.get(i));

                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Obrigado por utilizar o programa");

        }
    } while (escolha <= 7);
}


}
```

Minhas duvidas sao as seguintes:

no Case 1, nao estou conseguindo inserir nomes com espaco, ja tentei colocar nextLine, mas nao funciona, se eu coloco nextLine, na execucao do case1, só aparece para digitar uma vez o nome e matricula, tudo na mesma linha.

no Case 5, aonde preciso procurar o aluno, nao estou conseguindo fazer ele me retornar se o aluno esta no array e a sua posição no array, tentei tanto na forma acima como a forma abaixo:

```
System.out.println("qual aluno quer pesquisar");
            String p = choice.next();
            if (alunos.contains(p)) {
                System.out.println("o aluno " + p + " esta na posiçao " + alunos.indexOf(p));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Nome nao esta Inserido!!");
            }
```

E as 2 não funcionam.

Todos os outros cases funcionam sem problema nenhum.

Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Case 1:

O `Scanner` deixa uma quebra de linha na entrada após a chamada ao método `next()`, você pode descartá-la chamando o método `nextLine()`.

```
System.out.println("Digite o nome do Aluno ");
choice.nextLine(); // descarta quebra
String nome = choice.nextLine();
System.out.println("digite o numero de matricula");
int mat = choice.nextInt();
```

### Case 5:

Você está tentando ver se uma Lista de `Alunos` (onde os métodos `equals` e `hashCode` não foram sobreescritos por sinal) contém uma `String`, isso não funciona. Se você quer fazer uma busca linear nesse caso precisará comparar nome com nome:

```
for (int i = 0; i < alunos.size(); i++) {
    Aluno aluno = alunos.get(i);
    if (p.equals(aluno.nome)) {
        System.out.println("o aluno " + p + " esta na posiçao " + i);
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Esse aluno nao existe!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Opa, valeu pela resposta!, referente ao case 5, funcionou sem problemas nenhum, agora referente ao caso 1, se eu deixo a quebra como você informou, ele adiciona um nome vazio dentro do vetor, se eu executo o case 7 para imprimir os nomes, ele me retorna "vazio" - "numero matricula". Vou tentar aqui outros métodos, valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: Crazy, vocêm tem razão, troquei as bolas do caso 1, na verdade são os métodos `next*` que deixam a quebra de linha no *buffer*. Você deve descartar a quebra de linha antes de consumir o *input* da nova linha.

Comment: Realmente agora funcionou, valeu!